# Spring boot application with Elasticsearch Repository

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm developing a spring boot application which uses Elasticsearch as primary database. I'm still new to this technology stack, So I'm bit confusing with
manipulating datatypes in my model classes. My scenario is simply 1 user can have many followers & followers are also users in the application. In a RDBMS
environment this has to be a M:N mapping, I mean new separate table with user Id & follower Id but how I need to manage this in a nosql environment.

I did something like this, but i don't know what is the best approach for this. My User model is simply like,

```
@Document(indexName = "userdb", shards = 2)

public class User {

    @Id
    private String userId;
    private String name;
    private Set<String> followers = new LinkedHashSet<>();

  // getters & setters

}
```

In followers hash set i'm maintaining only user id's set as followers not objects because this will be a huge json data bulk due to followers can also have list of followers. In my UserServiceImpl class this is the code to follow a particular user.

```
 @Override

public ResponseEntity<GenericResponse> followUser(String followerId, String uerId) throws Exception {

        Optional<User> user = userRepository.findById(uerId);
        Optional<User> follower = userRepository.findById(followerId);
        if (!user.get().getFollowers().contains(follower.get().getUserId())) {
            User retrievedUser = user.get();
            retrievedUser.getFollowers().add(follower.get().getUserId());
            userRepository.save(retrievedUser);
            GenericResponse<String> genericResponse = new GenericResponse<>(ResponseMessage.SUC005.getMessage(), ResponseMessage.SUC005.getCode());
            return new ResponseEntity<>(genericResponse, HttpStatus.OK);
        }
        throw new ApiException(ResponseMessage.ERR008.getCode());
    }
```

This works fine but have a feeling like something wrong with it. I'm checking if user want to follow a another user, is he already exists in the follower list in that particular user. So if that user has thousands of followers I thinks this search will
do a huge impact to the application performance. Another approach came to my mind is maintaining a separate document for followers & insert records to that. So as I think model should be like this,

```
@Document(indexName = "followerdb", shards = 2)

public class Follower{

    @Id
    private String tblId;
    private String userId;
    private String followingUserId; // Also a user id
   //getters & setters
}
```

So what is the best approach? is there another way to handle this properly ? thinking according to RDBMS structure I got really confused. How to think scenario like this in nosql way? Assume a scenario like I want to load all followers (full objects) related to a particular user, In the code
that I have developed, first I have to retrieve all user id's from one database call & by iterating it needs to make separate database calls for each user and mapping it to DTO. But it' feels I'm getting things complicated without the knowing of true potential of using Elasticsearch databases.
When using spring data JPA this can simply do using EAGER fetching the models which is necessary with one database call. So I think do 2 database calls using Elasticsearch repository & mapping it to DTO is an extra cost in the performance wise. If some one can give me a better explanation
about what is the best nosql approach to solve this or thinking RDBMS mapping scenarios according to nosql way, I'm really appreciating it. Proper link that explain scenarios like this also will helpful.

Comment: I think the use case you are trying to implement is more suitable for graph instead of rdbms or elasticsearch. Especially elasticsearch strength is "search" and not a primary transactional database.

Comment: Elasticsearch is not a database and has nothing likke relations between index documents. As Shailendra wote, you might use a graph database. And why not a normal RDMS?

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the advice, I need to get familiarised with nosql databases. can you help me if I'm going to use mongo db, How this usecase have to implement ?